# What should I encode my passwords to?

Tags: database, encryption, sha1

I'm starting a new ASP.Net application from scratch. What should I use to encode passwords and what should my column be?

Just a simple varchar(512)? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're using SHA1 you're hashes are only going to be 48 characters long, so 512 is overkill.

I use SHA 256 with a salt.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the [Membership API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) that's included with .NET.  I believe it hashes passwords (and security answers) using salted SHA1.  If you still want to reinvent the wheel, you could still use this as a guide for best practices.

Comment: If you still want to reinvent the wheel, you should also realize that you're going to get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

People, please.

```
Encryption != Encoding != Hashing
```

These are 3 different terms that should not be used interchangeably.

Passwords should be *hashed* and *salted*, never *encrypted*, much less *encoded*. Use SHA as your hashing algorithm and remember to use a salt too. That's a very important countermeasure to avoid rainbow table attacks.

Also, all hash functions will generate an output that has a fixed size (32 characters in case of MD5, 40 in SHA1, etc.) so you don't need all that extra space.

#### References/Reading:

[MSDN: SHA1 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx)
[Just hashing is far from enough](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/03/just-hashing-is-far-from-enough-how-to-position-against-dictionary-and-rainbow-attacks.html)

Comment: To be fair there is an encoding step -- after you apply the salted hash, you generally *encode* the hash result as a base64 or hex string :)

Comment: @hobbs: If you're going to store the encrypted salt/hash in a database then there's usually no need for an additional encoding step. You'd just store them directly in a `VARBINARY` column, or equivalent.

Comment: @LukeH: That's not always convenient. It's much easier to deal with base 16 or 64, especially if you're storing the salt in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

The FormsAuthentication namespace has a handy method that you can use to hash a password for storing [in the database].

As others have mentioned, be sure to [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) your password.

FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltedPassword, "SHA1")

Answer (score -2):

I would take a look at the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace and devise a way to encrypt the passwords. Once you do that you can just take a look at the size of the encrypted passwords and create your column accordingly. Make sure you don't lose the encryption key of course. I would also have a different key in DEV than in PROD for added security. There are plenty of tutorials (and code) on how to do this in .NET.

Good luck!

Comment: here are some links: 

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/gsparamasivam/cryptencryption11282005061028am/cryptencryption.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10191114/systemsecuritycryptography.aspx

Comment: quantumSop: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Sergio See my post. Encryption, hashing and encoding are totally different, non-interchangeable terms.

Comment: Bad, bad advice. Do not encrypt passwords. Use a salted hash.

Comment: sorry guys, I meant hashed, wrong choice of words. I deserve the -1 :-)